# How to convert git branches to mercurial named branches?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Ive tried to use `--branchmap` option from [this docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension), but it does not helped.
I think that it is fundamentally possible to convert Git branches to Mercurials named branches - because we always can say what is the difference between Git repo *with* a branch and same repo but *without* that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that Git branches are just pointers to a commit. All commits that are ancestors of this commit are considered to be "on the branch", then. However, this later notion is broken if you see a commit only belonging to one branch, because simply having a second branch will create ambiguity in this regards: at least the root node is now in both branches.

Mercurial's named branches - for better or for worse - are effectively node-colorings. I.e. you color your nodes (commits) with one color (the named branch), and with one only. So fundamentally, it is not possible to convert Git branches to Mercurial named-branches and keep the meaning of "X is on branch Y" the same.

If you want a similar concept to Git branches in Mercurial, take a look at bookmarks.

Comment: *"...because simply having a second branch will create ambiguity in this regards: at least the root node is now in both branches."* Root must be in older branch.

Comment: What is "older branch"? The root branch could have been created in either one of the branches. There is no way to determine this in Git after the branch pointer advanced.

Comment: Indeed. But these conflicts can be easily resolved by hands in most cases, because oftenly there is sharp distinction between mainstream branches branches and secondary ones.

Comment: Counter-example: commit 0 is root on "master", next you create and checkout "devel" and make a commit 1 with it, next you checkout master again and commit 2 on it. Now commit 0 is on the devel branch, because that is the one with the older commit 1? With named-branches, that is a no-brainer, because the commits are colored already. With branch pointer, the information is lost.